# Why can't I paint on an existing texture?

Tags: texturing

I downloaded a texture model for a tutorial and wanted to fiddle with the texture painting tools. I somehow got it to work, but after I updated blender to an newer version it stopped to work. Tried to reinstall both versions and take the clean file.

link to the blender file
http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/74021

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: It works out of the box for me, just open the .blend and start painting.. What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the the image editor is in *paint* mode. There is a dropdown box in the header, that will change the mode. By default it is set to *view*, so no painting.
[image]